# Capture image from camera video feed into a canvas element, a Context2D instance, or an instance of ImageData

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, image-capture

I'm having trouble finding an example of how to capture an image from a camera video feed that works.

I've found [this great example](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/?redirect_from_locale=fr#toc-screenshot) and [this great one](http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/2013/08/webcam-to-canvas-or-data-uri-with-html5-and-javascript/) that gets me most of the way, but the image capture part fails.

How can an image be grabbed from a webcam video feed and placed in a canvas element, a Context2D instance, or an instance of ImageData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the canvas element. Try the code below:

```
var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463874/Webcam-and-Annotation-With-HTML5) might help.